# AWS EC2 PHP SDK - DescribeInstances With Tag Key and Value

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-php-sdk

I have EC2 instances tagged with key `environment` and value `production`. I am trying to return them using the following:

```
$result = $ec2_client->describeInstances(array(
    "Filters" => array(
        array(
            "Name" => "tag",
            "Value" => array(
                "environment=production"
            )
        )
    )
));
```

The above errors out.

How do I specify this method call in the correct manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct format is:

```
$result = $ec2_client->describeInstances(array(
    "Filters" => array(
        array(
            "Name" => "tag:environment",
            "Value" => array(
                "production"
            )
        )
    )
));
```

Comment: Should be "Values", not "Value".  Also, make sure you have no whitespace between the "tag:" and the tag name (not that Lloyd has whitespace, but I've seen other examples online with a space after the colon, and that will not work).

Comment: @JasonPriebe You're referring to PHP SDK V3.  This solution was catered towards V2

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.